# Notificação de uma data para outra R

Tags: r, notificação

DF = dados

```
  idade dt          nome
    2   02-02-2016  Marq
    8   05-05-2010  Andre
    24  06-06-1994  Sudre
    23  25-05-1995  Jaq
```

Esse é o meu df, preciso mostrar o nome da pessoa quando ela fizer 24 anos.
Por exemplo, quando faltar 90 dias para ela completar 24 anos, tenho que mostrar o nome, como posso fazer isso ?

Estou utilizando a linguagem R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não mexo com RStudio e Shiny, não sei como seria a automação dentro do que está desenvolvendo, mas eis como pode fazer a conta. Eu modifiquei seus dados de exemplo para ter mais de um aniversariante e uma pessoa com mais de 24 anos:

```
dados <- read.table(text = '
  idade dt          nome
    2   02-02-2016  Marq
    8   05-05-2010  Andre
    24  06-10-1994  Sudre
    24  25-10-1994  Jaq
    25  06-06-1993  Paulo',
  header = TRUE
)
```

Primeiro converta os dias para formato de data. Também acho mais prático ter os nomes como strings de texto ao invés de fatores. Você pode estabelecer esses formatos diretamente quando estiver lendo seus dados.

```
dados$dt <- as.Date(dados$dt, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
dados$nome <- as.character(dados$nome)
```

A função `Sys.Date` pega a data do sistema. Pode usá-la para calcular a diferença de dias entre a data atual e a data de nascimento. Imagino que você também vai precisar de uma comparação para excluir pessoas cujos aniversários de 24 anos já passaram.

```
aniversariantes <- 
  dados[
    Sys.Date() - dados$dt > 24*365.25 - 90 &
    Sys.Date() - dados$dt < 24*365.25 + 1,
    'nome']

cat( c( 
  'Faltam menos de 90 dias para o(s) aniversário(s) de 24 anos de',
  paste(aniversariantes, collapse = ' e ')
) )

Faltam menos de 90 dias para o(s) aniversário(s) de 24 anos de Sudre e Jaq
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, pq colocar  >(24*365.25-90) e <(24*365.25+1)

Comment: 'Date' trabalha com número de dias. 1 ano = 365 dias, mas temos anos bissextos a cada quatro anos, então uma conta melhor é multiplicar por 365.25. Você quer identificar quando faltarem 90 dias para o aniversário, então -90. Você pode usar `==` para ter apenas exatamente quando faltarem 90 dias. Supondo que ninguém verifique todo dia, é possível passar a data; nesse caso usar `>` quer dizer "faltam 90 dias ou menos". Mas nesse caso é preciso colocar também um limite superior, que corresponde a qualquer pessoa que tenha passado de 24 anos. São só ideias, veja o que te serve melhor.